# save hashed password in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, hash

I trying to hash the password and its working fine.But when inserting or updating into mysql database,i must save only hash password.

```
Controller.php (calling below method in add() method)

public function beforeSave() {
App::uses('Utitlity','Security');
  if(!empty($this->request->data['Mailinglist']['Password'])) {
  $this->request->data['Mailinglist']['Password'] = Security::hash($this->request-                 >data['Mailinglist']['Password']);
 }
 return true;
 }
```

But in the above code original password is stored in database,not the hashed one.Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave

You should use `$this->data` instead of `$this->request->data`.

To be sure try to `debug($this->data);`

```
public function beforeSave() {
    App::uses('Utitlity', 'Security');
    if (!empty($this->data['Mailinglist']['Password'])) {
        $this->data['Mailinglist']['Password'] = Security::hash($this->data['Mailinglist']['Password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use this code in your MailingList model, not in the controller like your question suggests, i.e. Move your beforeSave() method from the controller into the model and refer to cornelb's answer. Don't manually call a beforeSave() controller method in your add() action.

Comment: you're right, @jimmymadon I did not see that. This code belongs to the model. This can also be seen in the documentation page

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI,

$this->data has been deprecated. So now you should use $this->request->data.

Ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#controller

Answer (score 0):

You should use beforeSave metod in related model. And access data with 
`$this->data['Mailinglist']['Password']`

not `$this->request->data['Mailinglist']['Password']`